# Laravel Passport выдаёт Unauthenticated на посреднике auth:api

Tags: php, laravel, passport

1. Получаю Bearer-токен - следовательно, клиент зарегистрирован.
2. Пытаюсь получить доступ к маршруту с этом Bearer-токеном, где посредник **auth:api**, но выдаёт ошибку *Unauthenticated*.
3. Полез в посредник (**class Authenticate**) и на **protected function authenticate($request, array $guards)** условие **if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check())** выдаёт **false**.
4. Это при том условии, если **grant_type** - **client_credentials**, если **grant_type - password**, то его токен (!) аутентифицируется, и такой ошибки нет.
5. config/auth.php guards

```php
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],

'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

Кеш чистил, нового клиента для эксперимента создавал (токен получаю исправно), осталось монитор протереть - не могу понять причину того, почему аутентификация не проходит.

Comment: Теперь, после того, как токен другого грант_тайпа позволяет получить данные, уже думаю, что проблема может быть в самом токене.

Comment: Лезьте внутрь check, и смотрите на каком именно этапе получается false. Для этого и существует пошаговая отладка ...

Comment: При отправке запроса указываете header заголовок: Authorization: Bearer your_token?

Comment: curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/roles' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1 ........'

Comment: Тут уже начал думать: "а был ли мальчик", то есть это вообще возможно было ранее. Но на прод старые запросы с Bearer работают (не  все клиенты), что означает, всё-таки возможна отправка просто токена и получить доступ.